# How to get root pom file location in jenkins?

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am building a post build plugin for Jenkins which takes the reports in the maven project target folder to generate a consolidated report. But I do not know the location of target folder inside workspace. **Since the target folder will be in the same directory as my pom file, Is there any way I can get location of root pom file specified?**

Answer (score 0):

yes there is a way, if you have ssh access to executor (main or slave) go to it and locate build workspace, than you will see and get full path of your pom.xml file.

other option is to have several runs of jenkins job and use shell script pwd locate where are you and ls to see what you have there and it will give you idea how to proceed.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for replying...

I am quite a noobie in this area. So if you could provide the detailed explanation that would be really helpful.

Comment: do you have access via ssh to server/slave where you are executing your job ?

Comment: Hey, Thanks again.yeah. I do have access.

Comment: On other note, I read somewhere that there is a config file stored for each build and that file contains all information regarding that build. Do you think that will work?

Comment: And can you also take a look at other question..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774178/how-to-get-passed-suitefile-value-into-a-jenkins-plugin

Comment: config files are in different folder other then the workspace, so by default you do not have access to it from jenkins job execution and it is as it must be

second, in your job of jenkins do following , comment (if you are using pipeline) or disable all steps apart from source checking out and then add shell execution step and in it execute follwoing command:

``` pwd ; ls -al```

and check results , if that path is containig already the pom.xml file you are done, if not it will give you exact idea where is your pom.xml file